# A system reduces to one in row echlon form which has exactly one non-trivial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have a system $$\begin{align}a_1x+b_1y&=c_1 \\a_2x+b_2y&=c_2 \\a_3x+b_3y&=c_3\end{align}$$

I really dont understand how $a_1$ and $a_2$, etc connect, or if they have any connection at all!
I'm guessing i have to put it into a REF?
The system reduces to one in row echelon form which has exactly one non-trivial equation
Again I don't quite understand what it means, non-trivial means no 0's?
It also says all coefficients of x and y are not 0

Comment: how much linear algebra have you studied? do you know about the three types of solutions to a system of linear equations?

Comment: @DavidL unique solution, no solution or infinite solutions?

Comment: how about the rank of a matrix and it relates to the solutions you listed?

Comment: @DavidL I dont understand that bit?

Comment: $
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\
    a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
    a_3 & b_3 & c_3
  \end{array}\right]
$

Comment: $
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 0 & val\\
    0 & 1 & val2\\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$

Comment: Those should be the matrices you would get in order to have one non-trivial solution - a trivial solution is just (x=0, y=0)

Comment: @DavidL thank you very much, can i enter any value into val and val2?

Comment: No, they will be given to you based on your values for a1,b1, etc. you are basically RREFing the matrix to solve for x and y in a linear system